# Problems importing Turtle (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to use Turtle, but for some reason, it won't let me import it. I've tried `from turtle import *` (and that works) but if I try `print(dir(turtle))` or to use any functions, I get an error saying turtle is not defined.

`from turtle import Turtle` doesn't work but `print(dir(Turtle))` after using `from turtle import *` does work. However, prefixing commands with Turtle. ie `Turtle.color("red")` doesn't work.

Also, the demonstrations in the turtledemo folder work. I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation on this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: FWIW, it's generally best to avoid star imports. Use `import turtle`. Yes, you have to type `turtle.` before everything you're using from that module, but it makes the code a lot easier to read & maintain, and you don't clobber your namespace with all the stuff defined in the module.

Answer (score 1):

This imports `turtle` into the main namespace and is used as follows:

```
import turtle
turtle.something()
```

Thus, you now have an identifier in your main namespace, named `turtle`.

This imports all visible identifiers from turtle into the main namespace
and is used differently:

```
from turtle import *
something()
```

In this scenario, `turtle` is not in the main namespace. Its contents
are. Thus, `dir(turtle)` will fail, because that identifier isn't there.

Are you sure that `from turtle import Turtle` doesn't work? It worked
for me.

Comment: But of an update. I've found that the script works, but only if I've saved it in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/turtledemo

Comment: @BaronPaprika: That sounds like it's trying to import something from the local directory. Precisely what, we can't tell without seeing the code. Try to boil this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may figure it out in the process; if not, post the minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

If you import all from `turtle` then you have to use the `Turtle` object directly, like this:

```
from turtle import *

print(dir(Turtle))
```

and not like this:

```
from turtle import *

print(dir(turtle))
```